# When using the fancyhdr package, the header part repeats on every page on Latex. How can I avoid repetition as I want header only on 1st page?

Tags: latex, overleaf

I employed the use of "data-science-tech-resume-template" template on overleaf for building my own resume. The "_header.tex" file contains the use of 'fancyhdr' package and used lheader and rheader to display my name, enail id, contact etc. However, this header part repeats on evey page.
[1st Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87CxE.png)
[2nd Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VVys.png)

Below is the code for _header.tex:

```
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
    \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{}
    \lhead{
    
            \HUGE \skills \name \vspace{-.32em}
            \\ % feel free to adjust vspace to 0 
        {
                \color{highlight} \Large{\role}
            }
    } 
    \rhead{
        
            \city \\  % city 
            \phone \\ % PHONE    
            \href{mailto:\email}{\email} \\
            % \href{https://github.com/\github}{github.com/\github} \\% Github
            \href{https://www.linkedin.com/in/\LinkedIn}{linkedin.com/in/\LinkedIn}
    } 
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}% 2pt header rule
\renewcommand{\headrule}{\hbox to\headwidth{%
  \color{highlight}\leaders\hrule height \headrulewidth\hfill}}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setlength{\headheight}{90pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
```

I want the header to avoid repeating on the 2nd page. Can someone please help me out with this as I am new to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution that might help you.

- First, you need to move `\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}` from **_header.tex** to **TLCresume.sty**.
- Second, delete `\fancypagestyle{plain}` from **_header.tex** and change `\pagestyle{plain}` to `\pagestyle{fancy}`.
- Third, create a new file (e.g. test.tex) which contains the content of the 2nd page and change the code of **resume.tex**.

This is how the modified **resume.tex** file looks like.

```
\begin{document}

% input header goes inside "document"
\input{_header}

\input{sections/objective}

\section{Skills}
\input{sections/skills}

\section{Technical Experience}
\input{sections/experience}

\section{Education}
\input{sections/education}

\section{Activities}
\input{sections/activities}

% this is where 2nd page starts
\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\headheight}{50pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}

% content of the 2nd page
\section{Test}
\input{sections/test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @alexkanavos. Your suggestion worked pretty well. Just a small change in your solution, I didn't delete `\fancypagestyle{plain}` from **_header.tex**. It basically retained the header part where my name and the social media links are displayed. And it did not repeat in following pages.